# ERROR in ./~/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0

Tags: angular

Getting error while running the command "npm run build:prod".

Error:-

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./~/font-awesome-sass-loader/font-awesome-sass-styles.loader.js!./~/font-awesome-sass-loader/font-awesome-sass.config.js 6:30818-30880
 @ ./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./~/font-awesome-sass-loader/font-awesome-sass-styles.loader.js!./~/font-awesome-sass-loader/font-awesome-sass.config.js
 @ ./~/font-awesome-sass-loader/index.js
 @ ./src/vendor.browser.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the font-awesome library and add the dependency to package.json...

```
npm install --save font-awesome
```

Using CSS
To add Font Awesome CSS icons to your app...

// in angular.json

```
"build": {
  "options": {
    "styles": [
      "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
      "styles.css"
    ],
  }
}
```

Using SASS
Create an empty file _variables.scss in src/.

Add the following to _variables.scss:

```
$fa-font-path : '../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts';
```

In styles.scss add the following:

```
@import 'variables';
@import '../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome';
```

[Angular-cli include font awesome](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-font-awesome)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the issue came on production server. previously it is working perfectly.

Comment: What is your angular cli version

Comment: Node version: v4.8.0.

Comment: how did you add font-awesome to your angular project

Comment: I have not added manually. all these things setup during ng2-admin.